# Creating multiple nodes in one neo4j CREATE statement

Tags: neo4j

```
Create (sub:Subscription {name:"Paul",mobile:"8763xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}),
Create (sub:Subscription {name:"Peter",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}),
Create (sub:Subscription {name:"James",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}),
Create (sub:Subscription {name:"Bill",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"})
Return sub;
```

I am very new to Neo4j/Cypher.....Why do I get an "unexpected "C" error on the second Create. I am using 2.3.2 community edition. The manual says this should would work...I also tried the parameter example section 12.1 in the manual it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UNWIND [{name:"Paul",mobile:"8763xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}, {name:"Peter",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}] as subscriptions
CREATE (sub:Subscription)
SET sub=subscriptions
```

Or this:

[**Note:** This syntax is deprecated in Neo4j version 2.3. It may be removed in a future major release. See the above code using `UNWIND` for how to achieve the same functionality.
]:

```
{
  "subscriptions" : [ {
    "name" : "A",
    "email" : "a@b.c"
  }, {
    "name" : "B",
    "email" : "x@y.z"
  } ]
}

Create (sub:Subscription: {subscriptions}) Return sub
```

See, if that helps, or Refer this [link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create.html#create-create-multiple-nodes-with-a-parameter-for-their-properties-using-old-syntax).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav....I found the problem in the first script. I will take a look the parameter solution suggested

Answer (score 2):

The commas are illegal - this form works:

```
Create (sub1:Subscription {name:"Paul",mobile:"8763xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}) 
Create (sub2:Subscription {name:"Peter",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}) 
Create (sub3:Subscription {name:"James",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"})
Create (sub4:Subscription {name:"Bill",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}) 
Return sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4
```

If the you don't need a value back, then this will just create the nodes:

```
Create (:Subscription {name:"Paul",mobile:"8763xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}) 
Create (:Subscription {name:"Peter",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"}) 
Create (:Subscription {name:"James",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"})
Create (:Subscription {name:"Bill",mobile:"87638xxxxx",email:"info@aliant.com"})
```

Comment: Cool - please mark this as an answer so I'll get a few rep pts. Thx!